# Not able to access Json decoded array in php

Tags: php, json

I have Android application that sends a json string to PHP server and code is working fine on Android side but what i wants to do is to access JSon object php side and store it into database but i cant access it no matter what. I returned what i was receiving at PHP end to android to see what i am getting.

Thia is what application send to php servere

```
[
    {
        "title ": "First entry ",
        "address ": "Street 14, Lahore, Pakistan",
        "longitude ": "74.322",
        "latitude ": "31.5365"
    },
    {
        "title ": "Second entry ",
        "address ": "Street 14, Lahore, android ",
        "longitude ": "74.322",
        "latitude ": "31.5365"
    },
    {
        "title ": "Third entry ",
        "address ": "Street 14, Lahore, Lahore ",
        "longitude ": "74.322",
        "latitude ": "31.5365"
    },
    {
        "title ": "Fgghh",
        "address ": "Street 14, Lahore, Pakistan",
        "longitude ": "74.3219",
        "latitude ": "31.5364"
    },
    {
        "title ": "Shsagcg. ",
        "address ": "",
        "longitude ": "74.2695",
        "latitude ": "31.4626"
    },
    {
        "title ": "Ggggfb",
        "address ": "175 Block Q, Lahore, Pakistan",
        "longitude ": "74.2693",
        "latitude ": "31.4626"
    },
    {
        "title ": "",
        "address ": "Street 14, Lahore, Pakistan",
        "longitude ": "74.322",
        "latitude ": "31.5365"
    }
]
```

Thia is what PHP server send back to application

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title ] => First entry 
            [address ] => Street 14, 
            [longitude ] => 74.322
            [latitude ] => 31.5365
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title ] => Second entry 
            [address ] => Street 14, android 
            [longitude ] => 74.322
            [latitude ] => 31.5365
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title ] => Third entry 
            [address ] => Street 14, 
            [longitude ] => 74.322
            [latitude ] => 31.5365
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title ] => Fgghh
            [address ] => Street 14, 
            [longitude ] => 74.3219
            [latitude ] => 31.5364
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title ] => Shsagcg. 
            [address ] => 
            [longitude ] => 74.2695
            [latitude ] => 31.4626
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [title ] => Ggggfb
            [address ] => 175 Block Q, 
            [longitude ] => 74.2693
            [latitude ] => 31.4626
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [title ] => 
            [address ] => Street 14, 
            [longitude ] => 74.322
            [latitude ] => 31.5365
        )

)
```

This is what i receive and i tried to access single value with these commands + here is my php code.

```
<?php


$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$arr = json_decode($data, true);



print_r($arr);// This commands return above string in same format. 

?>
```

Commands i tried.

```
$title = $arr[0]['title'];// No success Eror = Undefined index
$title = $arr(0)// of course not success.
$title = $arr[0][1];
```

Is there any way to access this array.

Answer (score 4):

Your array keys appear to have a trailing space, so change to:

```
$title = $arr[0]['title '];
```

Comment: Or change the application that sends them, because this is probably an error.

Comment: application is fine since this format is send from php server. i will try to save save with this format . Application is simply sending and receiving.